# Can we get the color pallet used in Profile picture with initials of MS Teams through Graph API?

Tags: reactjs, photo

I have created a custom tab in MS Teams app using react. There I want to display a profile picture of Teams user. Can I get same color combination used in user profile picture when the user image is not available through Graph API?

If not any other way to get that color?

I am getting profile picture using following config:

```
      config = {
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        responseEncoding: "binary",
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url:
          "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" +
          element.id +
          "/photos/96x96/$value",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + body.token,
        },
      };
```